# Flexbox justify-content not working (weird extra margin on right side of children)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Sorry if this is a dumb question but I'm tearing my hair out as I can't see why this isn't working properly. The basics of my code are as follows:

```
.row {
    border: 2px solid goldenrod;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.one_half {
    width: 50%;
    border: 2px solid green;
}
```

Now, this works absolutely fine in a dummy page, but I'm trying to incorporate it into a Wordpress template page and for some reason there's a margin of 10-15px to the right of each child that I can't seem to shift. I've tried changing the class names in case of conflicts etc but I can't get it to budge. Just trying to get everything to fill the two boxes to the max height of the largest child (an image in this case) and have everything centred, splitting the page 50/50.

HTML as follows:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="one_half">
    Left Side
  </div>
  <div class="one_half">
    Right Side
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably WP code having an impact. Can't reproduce the problem with the code you provided.

Comment: Hmm.. Yeah it works fine in a test page. The content within the divs is being pulled from the WP content editor... maybe something weird that's being shoved in at the end of each statement in the editor? I stuck borders on the divs though and the margins are coming outside of the div area :S

Comment: *BANGS HEAD*... yes something fishy do do with class names. I renamed them something completely ridiculous and now it's working ffs :D